# How do I use ADB Input Events for users, other than phone owner?

Tags: adb, input-methods

I can easily automate input events using something like this:

```
adb shell input tap 300 300
```

And I am doing this, indeed, to automate configs exporting process for some owner installed apps.

Although, I would like to automate configs exporting process for apps installed by other phone users, but I had no success, so far. This is because other users can't enable ADB.

My phone is using Android 9 (Lineage OS).

Comment: @alecxs When I use ADB Input Events, the command is only going to work for user 0. I want to be able to use for users 11 and 12, for example.

Comment: so your question is how to enable usb-debugging for multi-user?

Comment: if that allows me to use `input` for other users: yes

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.singlebyte.devshortcut

Comment: @alecxs I really apreciate it but there's nothing I can do, since I don't know how to enable developer options for secondary users on Lineage 16. <3

Comment: the app does not work?

Comment: @alecxs no because developer options are not enabled for the secondary user I tried installing the app. I also have tried enabling developers tools by tapping "build number" many times...